# dialogflow slot filling implements in nodejs

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to process slot filling in nodejs with dialogflow?

I'm using the library @google-cloud/dialogflow.

I'm searching on google, no data founded so far.

can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

set slot filling on google dialogflow console

and match each conversation with same sessionID